# Boot Camp from USB DVD drive

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, macbook, boot-camp

I can't seem to be able to install Windows 7 64-bit on a 2008 MacBook (64-bit dual core) from an external USB DVD drive.

I've done the following:

- Performed a clean install of [Mac OS X Snow Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard)
- Installed all system updates
- Run Boot Camp Assistant - when the system restarts I get an error stating "no bootable disc"
- Used rEFIt, but I still get the same error
- Made a bootable USB drive from an ISO of the Windows 7 installation disc, but I still get the same error
- Tried using Windows 7 32-bit, Windows 7 64-bit and Windows XP, but I still get the same error

How I can resolve this?

Comment: What brand of external USB DVD drive? If not Apple, can you borrow an Apple one from someone and see if that works?

Comment: its a liteon.  Is this is a know issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't do it is because [Core Duo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_Duo) is technically not 64-bit, it's only 32-bit. It needs to be [Core 2 Duo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_2_Duo) - that's 64-bit. A lot people get that mixed up thinking that the Core Duo generation was 64-bit, and I was one of them. So your only alternative is just the Windows 32-bit option.

That will explain your 64-bit issue in regards to the other issue. I am not sure, do you know if the external DVD drive you're using supports Mac? If it doesn't, it will not work. There's firmware on the hardware that Mac will recognize in order to use it. In most cases, when you buy any hardware, it will still be for both Mac and PC.

Double check on that.